# Mouseover does not transition correctly when hovering a div for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having some trouble with my fade in Menu. I am using jQuery to `mouseover` and `mouseout`, which will add a class to the menu to make it darker.

When the menu opens, a `keyframe` animation runs, which sets the menu's background at black and then runs through until orange.

```
@keyframes menuinfade {
 0% {
  background-color: #000;
 }

 50% {
  background-color: #000;
 }

 100% {
  background-color: #e07a18;
 }
}

#menu.is-open {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 animation-delay: 2s;
 animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -moz-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -webkit-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -o-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
}
```

I'd like so that when the site's navigation Burger is hovered the background of the menu changes. I am doing this with `addClass/removeClass`.

```
burger.on('mouseover', function () {
        if (menuOpen == true) {
            menu.addClass('black-close');
        }
    });

    burger.on('mouseout', function () {
        if (menuOpen == true) {
            menu.removeClass('black-close');
        }
    });
```

Once the menu has been opened when you hover over the burger the animation is not smooth. It jumps from the finished keyframe state of orange, to the black hover `addClass`. I do have a `transition` on the CSS though:

```
#menu.is-open.black-close {
  background: #000;
  transition: 340ms ease
 }
```

When the menu opens, a `.is-open` class is added (also using `addClass`) to the main `#menu` div.

**Interestingly, when the menu is open and you hover the Burger (`#bk`) a second time or a third etc, it works, and just as it should, with a smooth transition, but not when you *first* hove it.** I can't figure it out.

---

```js
// Nav 
function theNavigationSystem() {

    // Menu Variables
    var menu = $('#menu');
    var header = $('header');
    var burger = $('header button#bk');
    var heading = $('nav > ul .column .nav__heading__title');
    var subMenuItems = $('nav > ul .column.site-map');

    // Full Screen Setup
    menuOpen = false; 

    burger.on('click', function () {
        if (!menuOpen) {
            menu.addClass('is-open');
            header.addClass('menu-open');
            header.addClass('transparent');
            heading.addClass('is-open');
            subMenuItems.addClass('is-open');
            menuOpen = true;
        } else {
            menu.removeClass('is-open');
            header.removeClass('menu-open');
            header.removeClass('transparent');
            heading.removeClass('is-open');
            subMenuItems.removeClass('is-open');
            menuOpen = false;
        }
    });

    burger.on('mouseover', function () {
        if (menuOpen == true) {
            menu.addClass('black-close');
        }
    });

    burger.on('mouseout', function () {
        if (menuOpen == true) {
            menu.removeClass('black-close');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {


    // Nav
    theNavigationSystem();


});
```

```css
header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 25px 0;
 transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 0.950, 0.100, 1.000);
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 100
}

 header.transparent {
  background: 0
 }

 header > .constraint, .content-grid.up-next .panel-headings, main.full > .constraint {
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }
 
 header #bk {
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 50px;
   z-index: 1000
 }
 
 #menu {
 position: fixed;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: #e07a18;
 color: #fff;
 transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 0.950, 0.100, 1.000);
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 20
}

@keyframes menuinfade {
 0% {
  background-color: #000;
 }

 50% {
  background-color: #000;
 }

 100% {
  background-color: #e07a18;
 }
}

#menu.is-open {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 animation-delay: 2s;
 animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -moz-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -webkit-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -o-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
}

 #menu.is-open.black-close {
  background: #000;
  transition: 340ms ease
 }

 #menu #main-navigation {
  margin: 210px 50px 0 16.785%;
  padding-bottom: 50px
 }

  #menu #main-navigation > nav > ul .column {
   width: 23.6%
  }

nav > ul .column span {
 display: block
}

 nav > ul .column span:first-child:not(.nav__heading__title) {
  margin-top: 85px;
  margin-top: calc( 50px + 1em + 20px);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.83rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: .036rem;
  text-transform: capitalize
 }

 nav > ul .column span:first-child {
  position: relative
 }

 nav > ul .column span:first-child::after {
  content:"\0020";
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  bottom: -12px;
  left: 0;
 }

nav > ul .column .nav__heading__title {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: 500;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 550ms ease;
}

 nav > ul .column .nav__heading__title.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 503ms
 }

nav > ul .column.site-map {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 750ms ease;
}

nav > ul .column.site-map.is-open {
 opacity: 1;
 transition-delay: 1.1s
}

#menu #footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 50px;
 left: 50px;
 width: 16.5%
}

#menu a, #menu a:visited {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none
}

nav ul > .column a {
 display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
<section id="footer">
    <ol>
        <li>Address
        </li>
        <li>Next Address
        </li>
        <li>SX-CC SL9 99S
        </li>
        <li class="contact-methods">
            <a href="tel:00000000">000000000
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Email Us
            </a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</section>
<section id="main-navigation">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="column">
                <span class="nav__heading__title">Site Map
                </span>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Homepage
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="column site-map">
                <span class="nav__heading">Projects
                </span>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">The Beldi
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/projects/belgravia/">Belgravia House
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Sahar
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Broonstone
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">London Road
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Tamon
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="column site-map">
                <span class="nav__heading">Online
                </span>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Facebook
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Instagram
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="column site-map">
                <span class="nav__heading">Find Out More
                </span>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/contact/">Contact Us
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/about/">Our History
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
</div>

<header>
<div class="constraint">
    <div class="logo">
        
    </div>
    <button id="bk">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </button>
</div>
</header>
```

---

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hkbv0xwq/5/

Comment: **Why on earth** would anyone even consider using jQuery for `mouseover` and `mouseout` related styling? **CSS has `:hover`.**

Answer (score 0):

First : Try using CSS transition for simple animations like this, it will make your work easier.

Second : I am not sure if this is the ideal solution for your problem but I can say the reason why you are not getting the animation for the first time is because `black-close` is never present in the DOM before you mouseover `burger` and hence its not taking its transition function in the first attempt.

To solve the problem, you should do the following :

1. Add `.menu-close` initially with `#menu`
2. Remove it in the complete function of `menu.addClass`
3. Make the `.black-close` style independent of `.is-open`

Check the below snippet for refference.

```js
// Nav 
function theNavigationSystem() {

    // Menu Variables
    var menu = $('#menu');
    var header = $('header');
    var burger = $('header button#bk');
    var heading = $('nav > ul .column .nav__heading__title');
    var subMenuItems = $('nav > ul .column.site-map');

    // Full Screen Setup
    menuOpen = false; 

    burger.on('click', function () {
        if (!menuOpen) {
            menu.addClass('is-open', function(){
              menu.removeClass('black-close');
            });
            header.addClass('menu-open');
            header.addClass('transparent');
            heading.addClass('is-open');
            subMenuItems.addClass('is-open');
            menuOpen = true;
        } else {
            menu.removeClass('is-open');
            menu.addClass('black-close');
            header.removeClass('menu-open');
            header.removeClass('transparent');
            heading.removeClass('is-open');
            subMenuItems.removeClass('is-open');
            menuOpen = false;
        }
    });

    burger.on('mouseover', function () {
        if (menuOpen == true) {
            menu.addClass('black-close');
        }
    });

    burger.on('mouseout', function () {
        if (menuOpen == true) {
            menu.removeClass('black-close');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {


    // Nav
    theNavigationSystem();


});
```

```css
header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 25px 0;
 transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 0.950, 0.100, 1.000);
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 100
}

 header.transparent {
  background: 0
 }

 header > .constraint, .content-grid.up-next .panel-headings, main.full > .constraint {
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }
 
 header #bk {
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 50px;
   z-index: 1000
 }
 
 #menu {
 position: fixed;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: #e07a18;
 color: #fff;
 transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 0.950, 0.100, 1.000);
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 20
}

@keyframes menuinfade {
 0% {
  background-color: #000;
 }

 50% {
  background-color: #000;
 }

 100% {
  background-color: #e07a18;
 }
}

#menu.is-open {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 animation-delay: 2s;
 animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -moz-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -webkit-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
 -o-animation: menuinfade 6.2s;
}

 #menu.black-close {
  background: #000;
  transition: 340ms ease
 }

 #menu #main-navigation {
  margin: 210px 50px 0 16.785%;
  padding-bottom: 50px
 }

  #menu #main-navigation > nav > ul .column {
   width: 23.6%
  }

nav > ul .column span {
 display: block
}

 nav > ul .column span:first-child:not(.nav__heading__title) {
  margin-top: 85px;
  margin-top: calc( 50px + 1em + 20px);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.83rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: .036rem;
  text-transform: capitalize
 }

 nav > ul .column span:first-child {
  position: relative
 }

 nav > ul .column span:first-child::after {
  content:"\0020";
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  bottom: -12px;
  left: 0;
 }

nav > ul .column .nav__heading__title {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: 500;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 550ms ease;
}

 nav > ul .column .nav__heading__title.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 503ms
 }

nav > ul .column.site-map {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 750ms ease;
}

nav > ul .column.site-map.is-open {
 opacity: 1;
 transition-delay: 1.1s
}

#menu #footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 50px;
 left: 50px;
 width: 16.5%
}

#menu a, #menu a:visited {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none
}

nav ul > .column a {
 display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="black-close">
<section id="footer">
    <ol>
        <li>Address
        </li>
        <li>Next Address
        </li>
        <li>SX-CC SL9 99S
        </li>
        <li class="contact-methods">
            <a href="tel:00000000">000000000
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Email Us
            </a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</section>
<section id="main-navigation">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="column">
                <span class="nav__heading__title">Site Map
                </span>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Homepage
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="column site-map">
                <span class="nav__heading">Projects
                </span>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">The Beldi
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/projects/belgravia/">Belgravia House
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Sahar
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Broonstone
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">London Road
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Tamon
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="column site-map">
                <span class="nav__heading">Online
                </span>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Facebook
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/">Instagram
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="column site-map">
                <span class="nav__heading">Find Out More
                </span>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/contact/">Contact Us
                </a>
                <a class="nav-areas" href="/about/">Our History
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
</div>

<header>
<div class="constraint">
    <div class="logo">
        
    </div>
    <button id="bk">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </button>
</div>
</header>
```

Hope this helps